# Removing borders from frame and panels in wxPython application

Tags: python, wxpython

I'm building an app that should contain a resizable sidebar area on the left (starting at 200px width) and a main area on the right that should expand to fill the remaining area. I've gone with the `SplitterWindow` method as it's the only one I think offers manual resize on panels. I'm experiencing some black borders around the individual panels AND the entire frame that I can't seem to get rid of. The borders on the individual panels disappear when I comment out the `make_canvas` calls, but the border on the frame is still there. Strangely enough if I resize the entire app window the borders flicker on and off. I suspect it's not actually a border issue but a `BoxSizing` issue, but I'm not sure how to take care of it.

Here's the code:

```
#! /usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import wx, random


class TDTaskBarIcon(wx.TaskBarIcon):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.TaskBarIcon.__init__(self)
        self.parentApp = parent
        self.icon = wx.Icon("images/icon_glasses.png", wx.BITMAP_TYPE_PNG)
        self.SetIconImage()

    def SetIconImage(self):
        self.SetIcon(self.icon)


class Sidebar(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        # tiled background
        self.bgimage = wx.Bitmap('images/noise.png')
        wx.FutureCall(50, self.make_canvas)
        wx.EVT_SIZE(self, self.make_canvas)
        self.SetBackgroundColour((229,226,218))

    def make_canvas(self, event=None):
        dc = wx.ClientDC(self)
        brush_bmp = wx.BrushFromBitmap(self.bgimage)
        dc.SetBrush(brush_bmp)
        w, h = self.GetClientSize()
        dc.DrawRectangle(0, 0, w, h)


class Main(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        # tiled background
        self.bgimage = wx.Bitmap('images/noise.png')
        wx.FutureCall(50, self.make_canvas)
        wx.EVT_SIZE(self, self.make_canvas)
        self.SetBackgroundColour((229,226,218))
        self.SetBackgroundColour('WHITE')

    def make_canvas(self, event=None):
        dc = wx.ClientDC(self)
        brush_bmp = wx.BrushFromBitmap(self.bgimage)
        dc.SetBrush(brush_bmp)
        w, h = self.GetClientSize()
        dc.DrawRectangle(0, 0, w, h)


# Create Tapedeck class
class Tapedeck(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.tbicon = TDTaskBarIcon(self)  
        self.tbicon.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnQuit, id=wx.ID_EXIT)

        splitter = wx.SplitterWindow(self)
        self.Sidebar = Sidebar(splitter)
        self.Main = Main(splitter)
        splitter.SplitVertically(self.Sidebar, self.Main)
        splitter.SetSashPosition(200)
        splitter.SetMinimumPaneSize(200)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(splitter, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizerAndFit(sizer)
        self.SetAutoLayout(True)

        self.InitUI()
        self.SetSize((800, 600))
        self.SetTitle('Tapedeck')
        self.Center()
        self.Show(True)

    def InitUI(self):

        panel = wx.Panel(self)

        # font styles
        header = wx.Font(18, wx.SWISS, wx.NORMAL, wx.BOLD, False, u'Helvetica')

        # create a menubar at the top of the user frame
        menuBar = wx.MenuBar()

        # create menus
        fileMenu = wx.Menu()
        helpMenu = wx.Menu()

        # export
        export = fileMenu.Append(wx.NewId(), "&Export", "Export Playlist",
                                     wx.ITEM_NORMAL)
        export.SetBitmap(wx.Bitmap('images/men_playlist.png'))

        fileMenu.AppendSeparator()

        # quit
        quit = fileMenu.Append(wx.NewId(), "&Quit\tCtrl+Q", "Quit the program",
                                   wx.ITEM_NORMAL)
        quit.SetBitmap(wx.Bitmap('images/men_quit.png'))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnQuit, quit)

        # put the file menu on the menubar
        menuBar.Append(fileMenu, "&File")

        # about tapedeck
        about = helpMenu.Append(wx.NewId(), "&About TapeDeck",
                                    "About TapeDeck", wx.ITEM_NORMAL)
        about.SetBitmap(wx.Bitmap('images/men_skull.png'))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnAbout, about)

        # put the help menu on the menubar
        menuBar.Append(helpMenu, "&Help")

        # set menu bar
        self.SetMenuBar(menuBar)

        # create a status bar at the bottom of the frame
        self.CreateStatusBar()

    def OnQuit(self, e):
        self.tbicon.RemoveIcon()  
        self.tbicon.Destroy()
        self.Close()

    def OnAbout(self, e):
        self.SetStatusText("Here's your help!")


# Run the application
def main():
    deck = wx.App()
    Tapedeck(None)
    deck.MainLoop()    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And screenshots:

Before resize ([source](http://cloud.smallparade.com/CL87)):

[image: Before resize.]

After resize ([source](http://cloud.smallparade.com/CLgw)):

[image: After resize.]

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are drawing those lines with the call to `DrawRectangle`.
If you want to eliminate the lines and still draw the rectangle you can do:

```
dc.SetPen(wx.Pen("WHITE",1))
dc.DrawRectangle(0, 0, w, h)
```

in the two `make_canvas` methods. It works in windows.

Comment: How would I tile the image using `SetPen`, though?

Comment: not sure what you mean. I already see (my) figures tiled. Did you try it ?

Comment: Ah! Thought you meant to replace `SetBrush`, not add to. Change the code to this: `dc.SetPen(wx.Pen("WHITE", 1, style=wx.TRANSPARENT))`